# Can larger antennas damage an HT radio?

Tags: antenna, receiver, ht

Can adapting a larger antenna such as a Diamond X-50 or larger mag mount damage an HT radio? Would it overload the receiver?

Comment: What, please, makes you see that as a problem?

Answer (score 12):

A larger antenna shouldn't damage a handheld radio. In a quiet area, it will make its receiver more sensitive, and it will radiate more power when transmitting.

---

Try to keep a receiving antenna away from a transmitter, to reduce the risk of damaging the receiver. I suspect we've all gotten away with it - my 50 W, 2 m mag mount was 30 cm from my car radio antenna and it wasn't damaged.

What you might find when adding an efficient, higher gain antenna to a handheld, is that it gets overloaded by strong signals near the amateur bands, making it *more difficult* to hear the station you want. (This isn't dangerous, the power levels are still very small).

Handheld radios are a compromise because of their small size and battery power, and often have a) less effective filtering and b) less robust receive amplifiers. Pre-amplifiers can be made more resistant to strong signals, by running them at a higher current. A handheld radio can't afford to waste 150 mW, so they use lower IP3, lower current amplifiers. c) finally the handheld expects to have a fairly poor antenna on it, which attenuates all the signals, so the receiver will be designed for that.

On a viewing platform on hilltop in the middle of a city, I've found that my handheld, with its short antenna, was nearly useless. All kinds of noises were breaking through and overlapping with the amateur signals.

Answer (score 11):

A larger antenna can mechanically damage an HT if it is physically supported by the HT (it can stress the connector on some designs), but if it's on a feed line instead it shouldn't matter.

Besides just being awkward to use that way, I wouldn't want to connect RG-8 directly to my HT with a rigid adapter for the same reason.

Answer (score 8):

No, it will likely improve reception because the HT antenna is severely compromised and done all the time in mobile applications to use an external antenna.